# Uploading multiple files into database with Laravel form

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to submit a form with the option to upload multiple files if the user wants. I keep getting the error "Undefined variable: data." Where did I go wrong?

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'description' => 'required|string',
        'date' => 'required|date|max:191',
    ]);

    if ($request->hasfile('file')) {
        foreach ($request->file('file') as $file) {
            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $fileName);
            $data[] = $fileName;
        }
    }

    return logbook::create([
        'title' => $request['title'],
        'description' => $request['description'],
        'date' => $request['date'],
        'file' => json_encode($data),
        'student_id_FK' => session('userID'),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `$request->hasfile('file')` is false

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart yeah, i wonder why

Comment: You should post your HTML file. If you have several inputs with `name=file[]`, the `hasfile->file('file')` will return false

Answer (score 0):

`$request->file('file')` is referring the `file` form data (i.e. a single file upload), so the `foreach` block is never executed. That's why `$data` is undefined.

You should handle multiple files with

```
foreach ($request->allFiles() as $file) {

...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it return an array if the inputs have the name `files[]`?

Comment: The input does have the name is file[] ,, and also i did as mention but still get the same error.

Comment: what if you `dd($request->hasfile('file'))`

Comment: it returns false eventhough i have selected a file

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form tag ?

Comment: @AhmedAboud yep got it. i think main prob is the code on the controller

Comment: please post the view

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the `$data` variable is only created if the `$data[] =` line is actually executed. It looks like that's not the case here. So simply define the array before adding to it to make it work if there are no files.

```php
$data = [];
// ...
$data[] = ...
```

In addition, there is a typo in the [`hasFile` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files):

```
if($request->hasfile('file'))
```

should be

```
if($request->hasFile('file'))
```

Note the case change.

Comment: i added it, but it just stores the "[]" into the database

Comment: In php you can use `$data[]` without declaring it as an array

Comment: You're right, but only if it actually enters the `foreach` loop, which doesn't seem to be the case here. I've updated my answer.